# How to handle compile time exception in pl/sql block?

Tags: sql, oracle, plsql, oracle10g

Actually its a silly quiestion to ask because why would you allow compile time exceptions in your code, But my situation is some what different.

Actually I am writing a pl/sql block in which I am fetching table names at run time and then using that table name in a query in which I have a where clause " where maker ='AUTO_MAST_MAK' ".. Now the problem is that in some table that "maker" column is not available so the block is not getting compiled.

Can any body help me in solving my problem.. or any suggestions " should I change my approach to my problem"

Comment: please post how you are calling the dynamic query with the where clause, did you try a BEGIN - EXCEPTION - END block ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Dynamic PL/SQL can handle compilation errors:

```
declare
    compile_error exception;
    pragma exception_init(compile_error, -06550);
begin
    execute immediate q'<
        begin
            does not compile
        end;    
    >';
exception when compile_error then
    dbms_output.put_line('PL/SQL Block did not compile.');
end;
/
```

Answer (score 1):

Why don't you check this column before generating of PLSQL block?

```
select table_name,column_name,data_type from user_tab_columns
```

Just check if the table has this column in runtime.